# converting csv to excel if header is mentioned multiple times in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv writted like this
0      (this is number which must be used as the row name)
header column1: data,data,data
header column2: data,data,data
10  (again, row name)
header column1:data,data
headercolumn2:data,data
What command do I have to use to make the numbers become column names , do I have to work on iteration or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading the data from a spark like output. Is it possible to coalesce into one file when writing the CSV so you do not have to worry about handling this at read.

Something like this when writing out:

```
outputData.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv(outputPath)
```

Or maybe even don't write your CSV with a header?